# How do i select the name and and the respective content in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

Imagine i have an .xml that looks like this:

```
<section>
                <one>true</one>
                <two>true</two>
                <three>true</three>
                <four>true</four>
                <five>true</five>
                
</section>
```

I want to select the name of the element and its respective value in xslt. Note that the "actual section" has 100+ elements selecting every single one would be quite tedious, is there an easier/faster way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `/section/*` selects all child elements of the `section` elements, depending on the XSLT version (2.0 or 3.0) you can then simply use e.g. `/section/*/concat(name(), ' : ', .)` to get a sequence of strings of `name : value` or `<xsl:value-of select="/section/*/concat(name(), ' : ', .)" separator="&#10;"/>` to output all or you can process `/section/*` with a template or for-each and output e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' : ', .)"/>` inside the template or for-each for XSLT 1.0.